# Complementary Colour Generator with Colour Wheel

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am trying to create a complementary colour generator using a colour wheel to select the main colour. I have managed to merge code from the 2 scripts/sites below however it does not auto update the colour, I was only able to get it to work with an input box and the need to click on the box and press enter to get the complementary colours to generate.

https://codepen.io/rakujira/pen/WZOeNq?editors=0010

http://design.geckotribe.com/colorwheel/

This is my version of the merged code -

https://codepen.io/Foster83/pen/KKzJObz

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I have had the same problem in the past. I will look again though.

Comment: Both work separate from each other, the issue is when using the colour wheel to populate the text box..

Comment: I have tried your fiddle and can't see a problem, so I'm misunderstanding the question. When I click on the color wheel the color changes in the slider and the hex value in the input box changes. I can then slide up and down if required to change hue and then all I need to do is press enter - I can't make it require a click on the inbox. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Click in the box and press enter, all the other colours should then change to complementary colours. It is the same if you type freely into the text box.

Comment: All the other colors change when  I press enter only, without needing a click in the input box (it's already selected). Nice application BTW.

Comment: Doesn't work that way on my website though, plus I'd like to be able to hide the box and have it just fresh from the colour picker wheel.

Comment: Ah, I understand, so you don't want the user to alter the color picked either by inputting different hex code in the inbox or by sliding the slider. Sorry I didn't get that the first time round. I'll have another look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222079/discussion-between-foster-and-a-haworth).

Comment: Sorry I missed the chat suggestion. I have put up an answer and a related JSfiddle.

Comment: Answer updated to keep the slider as well as the wheel. Any key press will select the color and cause the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarification in comments means the change needed is simpler than that given below. The requirement is that the slider remains and that there is just one key press to submit the color.

The only change required is to insert this line:

```
document.getElementById('jscolor').focus();
```

immediately after these lines

```
// Finally, use the position to update the picked color
            this$1.color.hsv = this$1._mouseTarget.input(x, y);
```

This was the initial answer - which allowed color picking only on the wheel, not the slider.

The question asks how to remove the need for the user to click on an input field and then click return after choosing a color on a color wheel. The requirement is for the action to occur immediately after the user has clicked on a color in the wheel and the input element which holds the hex value of the chosen color, and the slider, should not be visible.

As tracing exactly what happens on the various click events was difficult, I have instead created a few lines of code which simulate a user click on the input element followed by a keypress and have hidden the unwanted input element and stopped the slider from being created.

Fiddle can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahaworth/as7ydq4j/1/

The code needs changing in 3 places.

Look for the lines

```
// Finally, use the position to update the picked color
            this$1.color.hsv = this$1._mouseTarget.input(x, y);
```

and replace them with

```
// use the position to update the picked color
            this$1.color.hsv = this$1._mouseTarget.input(x, y);
// Simulate a keyup on the input jscolor element so the color change is immediately updated 
            var input = document.getElementById('jscolor');
            input.focus();
            var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
            ev.initEvent('keyup');
            input.dispatchEvent(ev);
          }
        }
```

Look for this line

```
<input type="text" id="jscolor" size="7" value="" tabindex="12" class="colour"/>  Click here and press enter once you've selected your colour   </table>
```

and replace it with

```
<input type="text" id="jscolor" size="7" value="" tabindex="12" class="colour" style="visibility: hidden;"/>  <!--Click here and press enter once you've selected your colour -->   </table>
```

Look for these lines

```
}), new slider(this.svg, {
  sliderType: "v",
  x: leftMargin + borderWidth,
  y: bodyWidth + sliderMargin,
  w: bodyWidth - borderWidth * 2,
  h: sliderHeight - borderWidth * 2,
  r: sliderHeight / 2 - borderWidth,
  marker: marker,
  border: borderStyles
})]; // Create an iroStyleSheet for this colorWheel's CSS overrides
```

and replace them with

```
})/*, new slider(this.svg, {
  sliderType: "v",
  x: leftMargin + borderWidth,
  y: bodyWidth + sliderMargin,
  w: bodyWidth - borderWidth * 2,
  h: sliderHeight - borderWidth * 2,
  r: sliderHeight / 2 - borderWidth,
  marker: marker,
  border: borderStyles
})*/]; // Create an iroStyleSheet for this colorWheel's CSS overrides
```

(or you could just leave them in and set the slider to display none)

Comment: Can we have the slider in still and achieve the same result?

Comment: I expect so, sorry I thought you want it removed. I'll have a look, but it'll be in an hour or so. But what do you want the interface to look like, at some point the user will have to indicate that they have selected the color they want.

Comment: Just ignoring the 3rd change makes it work. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Glad it worked. I just added a simplification, but of course can be ignored if not required.